# Selenium cannot interact with popup non-new window menu

Tags: python, selenium

I've tried literally everything. I'm at my witts end. I'm using Selenium to do 2 clicks, 1 clicks on a menu that populates the page with a popup, but every time click on it, it phases threw the layer and clicks on the layer behind it

```
ac.move_to_element(source).move_by_offset(731, 528).click().perform()
```

is the command im using right now. It clicks on a static image and moves down to where i need it.

I've used a bunch of different commands, and done it with every method, and when I was using elements (the elements are fed from a server, and generated so its not consistent, this is the only way to get it to consistently work) it would just close out of the menu.

I know it clicks on the layer behind it, because theres some highlighted text of where the click would of been if it it the proper layer

```
options = FirefoxOptions()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("/home/retkid/.mozilla/firefox/ipb9voff.default")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,options=options)
```

as my driver.

edit:I should clarify this doesn't make a new window.

Comment: Update the quesion with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: I've done that before, and that doesn't work. Any way to interact with it clicks on the layer behind it

Comment: _...I've done that before..._ what have you done before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML of the page, **It's possible that you need to switch window handle** in order to get to the context of the popup. Have a look if more window handles are added when the popup is opened. E.g. look at [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-access-popup-login-window-in-selenium-using-python/) for inspiration.

My suggestion is to start by outputting `driver.window_handles` before and after the popup is opened to see if any additional window contexts are added by the popup. That way you can see if you need to switch handle, and go on with the other parts of the guide.

The below code might work to switch to popup handle given that you start with 1 handle, and end up with 2 handles when the popup appears.

```py
# storing the current window handle to get back to dashbord 
main_page = driver.current_window_handle

# changing the handles to access popup 
for handle in driver.window_handles: 
    if handle != main_page: 
        popup = handle
```

Comment: So, this beautiful person applied the basic logic that, its basically an embedded popup! and i could just use the samething if it was a normal popup! genius.

Or you misunderstood me...